# Generating random variables from copula function at a given joint probability?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, copula, bivariate

I have one copula function, let's say a 2 dimensional Normal Copula with parameter of 0.5. I want to generate random variable pairs at given copula probability (e.g. 0.9). How can I do that? (since one copula function value correspond to more than one possible pairs).  Is it possible to generate the random variables based on their occurrence probability?

$$C (u,v)= c (F^{-1}(u),F^{-1}(v)),$$
where,
$C (u,v)$ is the joint distribution function of $ (u,v)$,
$F^{-1}(u),F^{-1}(v)$ are inverse distribution functions of the marginal distributions.$c(,)$ is the copula function.

I want to find random variable pairs $ (u,v)$  when $C (u,v)$ equals to certain value, lets say $C (u,v)=0.9$

In R `Copula` package, random pairs can be generated through `rCopula` function, however, the copula probability cannot be defined.

```
norm.cop <- normalCopula(0.5, dim = 2)
u <- rCopula(100, norm.cop)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you explain what is the "copula occurence probability" ? By searching with Google, I only found your crosspost... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964158/generating-random-variables-from-copula-function-at-a-given-copula-function-valu

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent, sorry for the cross post, I don't know where should i post this question.  About the "occurrence probability" is referring to the joint probability of the two random variables. This term has application in defining return period, see: 
http://www.sciencedirect.com.eproxy1.lib.hku.hk/science/article/pii/S1572312704000061#
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This article is not free access. The joint probability of which event ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I updated the question a little bit, and sorry that paper is not free access. Here is one with open access, http://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/17/3023/2013/hess-17-3023-2013.html

Comment: Assuming $C$ is available in R, you could use the `contourLines` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `c` denotes a copula (note: normally `c` is used for the density of a copula) and you plug in the marginal quantile functions (note: not necessarily `inverses distribution functions`) then the right-hand side of your displayed equation might not be defined. Reason: A quantile function lives on the real line, whereas copulas are only defined on the unit hypercube.

What you probably wanted to use is Sklar's Theorem: `H(x,y) = C(F(x), G(y))` (for `F,G` being the marginal distribution functions of the joint distribution function `H` and `C` being the corresponding copula if `F` and `G` are continuous). And you want to generate `(X,Y)` on the level set `{(x,y): H(x,y)=0.9}`. This problem is not uniquely defined. In other words, there are various methods to do that.

Even after reading your post multiple times, I still don't understand what exactly you try to do, but I feel that you should read more about `conditional distributions` and `conditional copulas` (as these are the approaches typically taken for what I *believe* is what you actually want to do); see Nelsen "An introduction to copulas" for the latter. The R package `copula` partly provides functionality for working with conditional copulas (see the function `cCopula()` for example), but you need to be more concrete with what you want to do on the theoretical side before going to the actual implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and recommended book. Really helpful! Thanks