# Generation of data from a bivariate distribution

Tags: computational-statistics, random-generation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non negative random variables with joint distribution 
\begin{equation}
F(x,y)=1-e^{-x}-e^{-y}+e^{-x-y-\delta xy}; ~~~x\geq 0,~~y\geq 0.
\end{equation}
How to generate a bivariate random sample of size $n$ for different values of $\delta$ associated with the same distribution.

Comment: check with copula generation

Comment: This question looks like a special case of the general problem addressed in (the near-duplicate) threads at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124865, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133881, and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149026. If they do not solve your problem, would you please edit this post to indicate where specifically you need help?

Comment: See pp. 583-584 in chapter 11 of Luc Devroye's book
[Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html)